# return data even if they are errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

I have a stored procedure, in which return a table containing `date`,`presence`,`total working hour` if present...

**`Total Working Hour`** is calculated in a separate function that return a decimal value, **But** sometimes employees have a mistakes in data, like a duplicate punches or punch (out or in) for twice,
if any of the above scenario exist the function returned an error, and therefore The SP return error...

My request is when any error is occurred, i want to return 0 or -1 or whatever instead of the error, to forces the SP to return data even if they are errors..
The Error generating every time is :

```
SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value.
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=
```

So I want in every time when this error occurred, to return a value instead of it,

the SP Code is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SM_GetAttendance]
(
    @StartDate date ,
    @EndDate date ,
    @EmployeeID NVARCHAR(6) 
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE dte_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
WITH T(date)
AS
( 
SELECT @StartDate 
UNION ALL
SELECT DateAdd(day,1,T.date) FROM T WHERE T.date < @EndDate
)
SELECT date FROM T OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

    DECLARE @date NVARCHAR(20);
    CREATE TABLE #datetable(date DATETIME,Status NVARCHAR(50),nbOfWorkingHour DECIMAL(36,2))

--SELECT date FROM T 
set @date = ''
OPEN dte_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dte_Cursor INTO @date

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
insert #datetable 

SELECT
        cast((select distinct Convert(Nvarchar(12),date,102) from Attendance where date = @date
                            and employeeid =@EmployeeID ) as nvarchar(30))
                        date

,CASE WHEN  EXISTS (select 1 from Attendance 
                        where employeeid=@EmployeeID and date = @date)
                then 'Present'
                else 'absent'
                        end Status

,dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(@date,@EmployeeID) as numberOFWorkingHour
FETCH NEXT FROM dte_Cursor INTO @date
END 

CLOSE dte_Cursor;
DEALLOCATE dte_Cursor;
end
```

And The Part of the Function Code that get the error is:

```
SET @From = (SELECT Time from @Tbl where date = @Date AND (EmployeeID=@employeeID OR ISNULL( @employeeID, '') = '') and funckey = 'EMPIN')

set @to = (CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Times from @Tbl where dates = @Date AND (EmployeeID=@employeeID OR ISNULL( @employeeID, '') = '') and funckey = 'EMPOUT' )
then (SELECT Time from @Tbl where date = @Date AND (EmployeeID=@employeeID OR ISNULL( @employeeID, '') = '') and funckey = 'EMPOUT' )
else (SELECT Top 1 Time from @Tbl where date = dateadd(day,1,@Date) AND (EmployeeID=@employeeID OR ISNULL( @employeeID, '') = '') and funckey = 'EMPOUT')
end)

return ROUND(CAST(DATEDIFF(@From,@to) AS decimal)/ 60,2)
```

the following piece of code that get the error :

```
(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Times from @Tbl where dates = @Date AND (EmployeeID=@employeeID OR ISNULL( @employeeID, '') = '') and funckey = 'EMPOUT' )
```

IN this example the employee have two out punches like the below :

```
EMPID       Date            Time            Status
123         2015-10-22      06:54:42 AM     OUT 
123         2015-10-22      04:35:02 PM     OUT
```

So how to how to handle this state?

Answer (score 0):

You can just change

```
(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT Times from @Tbl where dates = @Date AND (EmployeeID=@employeeID OR ISNULL( @employeeID, '') = '') and funckey = 'EMPOUT' )
```

To this

```
(CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT top 1 Times from @Tbl where dates = @Date AND (EmployeeID=@employeeID OR ISNULL( @employeeID, '') = '') and funckey = 'EMPOUT' )
```